# Send my app programmatically in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this flutter app fully done but I want to add a button that say share when user clicks on this button it share the entire apk to a friend either using Xender or any other sharing medium.

I kno it may not be possible on iOS but I want to do this on flutter Android.
How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you upload to apk to any storage hosting then send the link when click share.

Another way is to use [Flutter share package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share) , you can take a look at the documentation for more info